# FVM/Flutter unable to find git on non-administrator account on Windows

Tags: windows, git, flutter

As an administrator, fvm works:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> fvm flutter --version
Flutter 3.7.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c07f788888 (3 days ago) • 2023-02-22 17:52:33 -0600
Engine • revision 0f359063c4
Tools • Dart 2.19.2 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

When I try to run it from my user account though, it does not, even though its obviously in my path:

```
C:\Users\saxto>fvm flutter --version
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
C:\Users\saxto>where.exe git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

[image: [![Screenshot of my PATH environment variable][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfanx.png]